# Unique together and sending null with nested serializer cause constranit error

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I'm having an issue with making both of those two work... Did I miss something?
I'm sending Json to my post(creating comment):

```
{
"content":"message",
"myuser":{
    "username":"ztestz",
    "source":"test",
    "email":null}
}
```

Which answers to unique_together fields for this model:

```
class MyUser(models.Model):
    username = CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    source = CharField(max_length=50, default='discord')
    email = EmailField(null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('username', 'source',),('email', 'source',))
```

My nested serializer contains given create:

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    myuser = MyUserSerializer()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        myuser_data = validated_data.pop('myuser')
        print(validated_data)
        # myuser = MyUser.objects.filter(
        #     Q(name=validated_data['username'], source=validated_data['source']) | Q(name=validated_data['email'], source=validated_data['source']))
        # print(myuser)
        myuser = MyUser.objects.get_or_create(**myuser_data)
        print(myuser)
        # myuser = MyUser.objects.get_or_create(myuser, defaults={'source': validated_data['source'], 'username': validated_data['username'], 'email': validated_data['email']})
        comment = Comment.objects.create(user_related=myuser[0], **validated_data)
        return comment
```

For unknown to me reason, get_or_create returns constraint invalidation, even through the item definitely exists:

```
{
"myuser": {
    "non_field_errors": [
        "The fields username, source must make a unique set."
    ]
}
}
```

Could anyone explain to me, what is happening in here? Is there some kind of requirement for nested serializers to work with unique_together, or get_or_create to contain certain data? The data in **validated_data contains all the fields that would be included in default...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it seems there is no way to do it, except for removing `unique_together`; the constraint check happens before.

Also, the name of `myuser` should be `user_related` (that's the name of field in my model that was a foreign key). Otherwise, it will say stuff like "X" has no attribute "Y". It must be exactly the same.